# Finding the number of letters that occur more than a specific number of times on python?

Tags: python, string

For example

```
String = "The boy who cried wolf made many many silly mistakes."
def f(n):
```

.

```
f(3)
```

should output:

```
4
```

since  only 2 letters, "a" , "m" , "y" and "e" occur more than three times.

What I've tried and where I've managed to get to so far:

```
 String = "The boy who cried wolf made many many silly mistakes."
 a={}
 def f(n):
  for s in String:
    if s in a:
      a[s] +=1
    else:
      a[s] = 1
```

I'm not sure what to do next

Comment: What's about `y`, `e`?

Comment: check e one more time

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. But I can request that you use a function like f(n). I'm not sure what exactly collection modules are at this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter` is certainly a good way to do this; however, if you don't want to import anything, consider the following.

```
string = "The boy who cried wolf made many many silly mistakes."
def f(n):
    alpha_chars = filter(lambda char: char.isalpha(), string)
    greater_chars = 0
    for char in list(set(alpha_chars)):
        if string.count(char) > n:
            greater_chars += 1
    return greater_chars
```

Where `f(3)` will output `4`.

However, [as explained here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil),  it's better to use the string as an argument.

```
my_string = "The boy who cried wolf made many many silly mistakes."
def f(string, n):
    ...
```

You can then call with `f(my_string, 3)` which will output `4`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Counter Class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) from collections module.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> string = "The boy who cried wolf made many many silly mistakes."
>>> Counter(string)
Counter({' ': 9, 'e': 4, 'a': 4, 'y': 4, 'm': 4, 's': 3, 'i': 3, 'o': 3, 'l': 3, 'n': 2, 'd': 2, 'h': 2, 'w': 2, 'T': 1, 'b': 1, '.': 1, 'k': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'c': 1, 'f': 1})
>>> m = 0
>>> c = Counter(string)
>>> for i in c:
        if i.isalpha() and c[i] > 3:
            m += 1


>>> m
4
```

Defining it as a seperate function.

```
from collections import Counter
def f(n):
    c = Counter(n)
    m = 0
    for i in c:
        if i.isalpha() and c[i] > 3:
            m += 1
    return m
stri = "The boy who cried wolf made many many silly mistakes."    
print f(stri)
```

Comment: Now it's perfect answer

Comment: Good answer, but your function does not support any arbitrary number.

Answer (score 3):

Using [**`collections.Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) and [**`sum`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

```
from collections import Counter    
s = "The boy who cried wolf made many many silly mistakes."
sum(1 for k,  v in Counter(s).items() if v > 3 and k.isalpha())
```

**Output**

```
4
```

Or you can define a function.

```
def f(s, n):
    return sum(1 for k,  v in Counter(s).items() if v > n and k.isalpha())
```

and

```
f(s, 3) #return 4
```